# Use key/value inheritence but leave it out of the result in pyyaml

Tags: python, inheritance, pyyaml

PyYAML is pretty cool in respect to inheritance of the key/value pairs, but is it possible to not include the following base_value_structure in the final structure.

```
Default_profile: &Default_profile
    base_value_structure: &base_value_structure
        path_to_value: 'path to element'
        selector_type: 'XPATH'
        required: false
    title:
        <<: *base_value_structure
        path_to_value: "//div[@id='ctitle']/text()"
```

After parsing the config above, the base_value_structure is in the result. Can I prevent this behavior or do I need to filter it by hand?

Desired result:

```
{"Default_profile": {
    "title": {
        "path_to_value": "//div[@id='ctitle']/text()",
        "selector_type": "XPATH",
        "required": False }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to filter this out by hand. There is no provision in the [specification](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html) of merge keys.

You could, if you would not load mappings as Python dicts, but as more complex types, filter these "base" mappings out automatically, but at the cost of complicating the syntax of the YAML file.

It should also possible to tweak the parser to keep a list of mappings used as base and delete those that are used. Or alternatively, if only "base" mappings have an anchor, delete only those. Neither of these can be done with PyYAML as is.

However it is not necessary that the anchored mapping has the same anchor name as the key. The anchored mapping doesn't have to be a key value (as it is in your example) at all. By reordering the YAML file you can much more easily remove the "base" or even multiple bases:

```
from pprint import pprint
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

yaml_str = """\
-
  - &base_value_structure
    path_to_value: 'path to element'
    selector_type: 'XPATH'
    required: false
  - &base_other_structure
    key1: val1
    key2: val2
- Default_profile: &Default_profile
    title:
        <<: *base_value_structure
        path_to_value: "//div[@id='ctitle']/text()"
"""

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)[1]
pprint(data)
```

gives:

```
{'Default_profile': {'title': {'path_to_value': "//div[@id='ctitle']/text()",
                               'required': False,
                              'selector_type': 'XPATH'}}}
```

In the above I used my [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) library, which is a derivative of PyYAML, which for this example should work the same as PyYAML, but it would preserve the merge information if you used its round-trip loader/dumper.